# Хотите, я разбужу для вас кота?

Tags: литература

Попалась в сети такая картинка:

[image]

Исходник, насколько я знаю, фраза самого Бродского: "Хотите, я разбужу для вас кота?" Она уже, можно сказать, стала интернет-мемом. А при каких обстоятельствах и, главное, к чему вообще была сказана эта фраза?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вроде как Бродский говорил её неоднократно - в знак особого расположения к гостям.

Не знаю, правда, идет ли речь о реальном коте, который якобы любил спать в лучшем кресле, или это было идиомой уже в устах самого Бродского, но смысл был именно такой: оказание уважение, проявление гостеприимства...

По вашей картинке это, кстати, не трудно сообразить: намек очевидный.

(+)
Посмотрел по интернету, кроме этой, для меня очевидной, версии, есть еще некоторые намеки, что Бродский, дескать, это ***в себе*** будил кота. Типа, "не буди во мне зверя." Ох, не знаю... Странноватая идея. Непонятная.

(++)
Вот здесь несколько совсем коротеньких эссе о писателях и их котах.
В т.ч. и про кота Бродского. Проверить факты не могу, да и не надо это: конкретно к ответу на вопрос ничего не добавляет. Читается легко и настроение "кошатникам" поднимает.

[Великие коты и их домашние писатели | znay-ka.blogspot.ru](http://znay-ka.blogspot.ru/2014/04/blog-post_1.html)

Comment: Насколько я помню по одному интервью, у него реально был кот, по кличке СССР - он объяснял, что в кошачьем имени должны быть буквы "с", в связи с особенностями слуха у кошек.

Comment: Да у него котов много было. Вот про СССРа, правда, не слышал...
Вопрос в тем, реально ли он их будил для гостей или это была фигура речи?!

Comment: Отличная кличка для кота!)))

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, это интервью 1988 года журналу "Сеанс" стало источником:

[Иосиф Бродский. Большая книга интервью | КулЛиб](http://coollib.com/b/149087/read)

"- Кота, что ли, разбудить? Замечательная история в связи с разбуженным котом.
В шестидесятых годах в Югославии к моему другу приехала какая-то дама, то ли лейбористка, то ли консерватор, в общем из парламента. Он колоссально воодушевился. Дело происходило зимой. Он не знал, как ей продемонстрировать свои сантименты. У него был свой собственный зоопарк на том острове, где он жил, и вот, чтобы продемонстрировать ей свою страсть, он сказал: хотите, я для вас разбужу медведя? Дело было зимой. И медведя разбудили. Ха-ха. Хотите, я разбужу для вас кота?"

Comment: Да, интересно. Но вроде бы фраза про кота звучала от Бродского задолго до 88 г. Тут он вроде как просто повторил свою присказку.